# Run Puppetter script from PHP

Tags: php, puppeteer

I have installed Puppeteer on Centos 7 and ran "node test.js", which can create a PNG correctly.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function runTest() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox'],
    });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com.tw');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example2.png'});

  await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
}

runTest();
```

Then I tried to execute that from a PHP script:

```
$command = 'node test.js';
shell_exec($command .' 2\>&1');
```

This works to create PNG if I run on the command-line as `php test.php`, but it can't create PNG when I run it on browser, like
`http://192.168.0.55/puppeteer/test.php`

The error is：

```
Error: ErrorEvent {
\[Symbol(kTarget)\]: WebSocket {
\_events: \[Object: null prototype\] { open: \[Function\], error: \[Function\] },
\_eventsCount: 2,
\_maxListeners: undefined,
\_binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
\_closeCode: 1006,
\_closeFrameReceived: false,
\_closeFrameSent: false,
\_closeMessage: \<Buffer \>,
\_closeTimer: null,
\_extensions: {},
\_paused: false,
\_protocol: '',
\_readyState: 3,
\_receiver: null,
\_sender: null,
\_socket: null,
\_bufferedAmount: 0,
\_isServer: false,
\_redirects: 0,
\_url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:33060/devtools/browser/c9968cc9-8411-4558-a50a-8d3fbe4ffc22',
\_originalIpc: false,
\_originalSecure: false,
\_originalHostOrSocketPath: '127.0.0.1:33060',
\_req: null,
\[Symbol(kCapture)\]: false
},
\[Symbol(kType)\]: 'error',
\[Symbol(kError)\]: Error: connect EACCES 127.0.0.1:33060 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
at internalConnect (node:net:1041:16)
at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (node:internal/async_hooks:464:18)
at node:net:1134:9
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
errno: -13,
code: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 33060
},
\[Symbol(kMessage)\]: 'connect EACCES 127.0.0.1:33060 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)'
}
```

Can anyone explain why it doesn't work from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

finally， I find the error is because selinux .
SO

> sudo sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log

It WILL see some suggestion and run it on the command-line。
then it can create a PNG correctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).